# combine multiple data in single column to single row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

the input is one column where the output what I should get is in F column as shown in the screen shot kindly anyone help on this

Comment: What did you try, in order to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like a VBA solution or you do not use Excel365/2019, try the next code, please:

```
Sub testTransposedString()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arr1D
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("E2:E" & lastR).Value
  arr1D = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 1))
  sh.Range("F2").Value = Join(arr1D, " ")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TEXTJOIN()` function if you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd>.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,E2:E5)
```

[image]

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN` is not limited to `Excel365`. It also works with Excel 2019 Professional.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thats good. I do not tried yet `Excel 2019`. From `Excel 2016` jump to `Office365`. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Actually this can be checked at the official documentation [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) where it says *"Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac, Excel for the web, Excel 2019, Excel 2019 for Mac"*